# SMTP logger in log4net not sending very long emails

Tags: email, smtp, log4net

I have configured the SMTP logger in my configuration as this:

```
<appender name="SmtpEndUserAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
                     <to value="someReciever@sjm.com"/>
                     <from value="serviceAccount@sjm.com"/>
                     <subject value="Error occured in the XML Conversion Utility"/>
                     <smtpHost value="smtp server name"/>
                     <bufferSize value="1024"/>
                     <lossy value="false"/>
                     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                           <conversionPattern value="%date{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
                     </layout>
              </appender>
```

The thing is, If the message is small it sends fine, but if the appender finds too long a message it simply passes through the code block without receiving any email in inbox.

```
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(Constants.ENDUSEREMAILLOGGER);
log.Info(string.Format(Constants.EMAILERRORMESSAGETEMPLATE, unprocessedFile, ex.Message));
```

the ex.message can sometimes get crazy long (like 2000 lines or something) as I use string builder while looping over 5000+ rows and gathering all errors.

Do we need to increase buffer size? Why this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your short emails are sent via log.Error whereas your large ones are using log.Info?

The bufferSize is the number of non-error events that are buffered before being sent vias email. In other words, if you aren't using log.Error, then you won't get any emails until you have called log.info 1024 times and then you get one email containing all 1024 messages.

But log.Error will flush the buffer which will send an email immediately.

Another possibility is that the email containing all 1024 messages is being rejected as too big.